# in R, why does %% behave differently for decimal numbers?

Tags: r, division

in R, I want to check if a number is a multiple of another. this works well for integers

```
> 124%%1
[1] 0
> 124%%2
[1] 0
```

But for some mysterious reason doesn't work well with decimal numbers, any idea why `1.05%%0.05` is **not** 0?

```
> 0.05%%0.05
[1] 0
> 1.05%%0.05
[1] 0.05
```

Comment: Also read - [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expected a 0 result then perhaps you would be satisfied with the results of multiplying both arguments by 100 (making these integer or at least close to them. )

```
(100*1.05)%%(100*0.05)
[1] 0
```

See @akrun's answer for "why".

Answer (score 6):

According to `?"%%"`

> %% and x %/% y can be used for non-integer y, e.g. 1 %/% 0.2, but the results are subject to representation error and so may be platform-dependent. Because the IEC 60559 representation of 0.2 is a binary fraction slightly larger than 0.2, the answer to 1 %/% 0.2 should be 4 but most platforms give 5.